# Animated EditText bug on Android API 10

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I'm facing a trouble with the NineOldAndroid library, apparently there's some kind of a glitch, I wanna animate (move at ~20dp from the screen's top) my EditText when the user click on this one, works perfectly on API > 11 (...).

But on previous versions when I animate my EditText, this one move on top exactly as its supposed to, but for a reason I don't understand ( and which I didn't found yet, thanks to my best buddy Google )  the EditText move outside the screen even though it has enough place! 
And If I close the keyboard (cause I focused the edittext etc...) I can only get back on the EditText by clicking on the EditText's start position.

I think the picture below would be more comprehensible :)

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for any of your answers :D

Comment: Having the same issue with ScaleAnimation. I think the reason is Android is transforming control's visual representation only. I guess if you check animated control bounds and position they will be unchanged after animation e.g. bound and hit rects remain the same.